# Android Constraint Layout Dimension Ratio Not Working with Wrap Content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

Hi I just want to display two textviews in constraint layout like below

[image]

What I have done so far is horizontally chain these textviews and since I need them to be squares, set the size as a ratio (constraintDimensionRatio). 
This is the code.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorBlueGrey"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView8"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorBrown"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

Now the issue is when I'm changing the **constraint layout's**

> layout_height

into

> wrap_content

like this,

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

It will display like below.

[image]

Yep. It won't display at all. **Any idea to fix this?** 
I'm using constraint-layout:1.1.0.

Comment: This id because you constraintlayout is set to wrap content, And its children doest not have any content to which it has to wrap itself.

Comment: @parekhkruti26 Sorry I didn't get it.

Comment: Sorry some typos were there in previous comment. Fixed them. This is because your constraintlayout is set to wrap content, And its children doest not have any content to which it has to wrap itself.

Comment: The child views doesn't have a fixed height, so the parent cannot wrap content. Since you're using dimension ratio and setting height to match constraint for child views, wrap content wont work for parent view.

Comment: @SasiKanth So currently there is no way of doing this, except setting the height to match parent, isn't it? Otherwise, I should use a library or custom view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result by using a vertical `Guideline` set at 50% of the parent width and constraining both `TextViews` to it and maintaining 1:1 ratio, like so:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorBlueGrey"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorBrown"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Note that the `TextViews` no longer create a chain and the margins at the end of the first `TextView` and at the start of the second `TextView` had to be changed to make it `8dp` in total between the views.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the attribute: android:layout_height="0dp" change android:layout_height="wrap_content".

Comment: Thanks, It is working but the squares are very small. I want the squares to be large as the 1st image above. Any suggestions for that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve aspect ratio and parent layout must be "wrap_content" (useful for text views with variable text), you can add a fake view, which keeps aspect ratio and other elements must be constrained to this view:

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout     
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/ratio_constraint"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="122:246"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/ratio_constraint"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/ratio_constraint"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ratio_constraint"
        tools:text="The TextView which can extend the layout" />

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]